# Why background process could be interrupted after some time of successful execution? (exit code 248)

Tags: c, linux, process, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I wrote a C program for Raspberry Pi which reads Wiegand card ID from two readers and put in a text file. Program is based on [pigpio library](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/) and in fact is just modified example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pigpio.h>
#include "wiegand.h"


void callback1(int bits, uint32_t value)
{

    FILE *saved = stdout;
    stdout = fopen("log_readers.txt", "a");
    printf("Reader_1: bits=%d value=%u\n", bits, value);
    fclose(stdout);
    stdout = saved;
}

void callback2(int bits, uint32_t value)
{
   FILE *saved = stdout;
   stdout = fopen("log_readers.txt", "a");   
   printf("Reader_2: bits=%d value=%u\n", bits, value);
   fclose(stdout);
   stdout = saved;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   Pi_Wieg_t * w1;
   Pi_Wieg_t * w2;
   if (gpioInitialise() < 0) return 1;
   w1 = Pi_Wieg(14, 15, callback1, 5);
   w2 = Pi_Wieg(23, 24, callback2, 5);
   sleep(300);
   Pi_Wieg_cancel(w1);
   Pi_Wieg_cancel(w2);
   gpioTerminate();
}
```

When I compile and run the program everything works fine 
(checked log_readers.txt file with `tail -f`)

When I run the binary in background mode

```
sudo ./all_readers.bin &
```

it's also executed correctly, but after some time is stop working.

Immediately after running ps see the process:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/sandbox $ ps ax | grep all_readers
 3768 pts/0    S      0:00 sudo ./all_readers.bin
 3769 pts/0    SLl    0:00 ./all_readers.bin
```

But if I run same command after 5 minutes no output in ps:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/sandbox $ ps ax | grep all_readers
 3782 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto all_readers
[2]-  Exit 248                sudo ./all_readers.bin
```

Looks like proccess became terminated. According to my observations it's not depending on program-related events like reading card. Also it's enough free memory in RAM and on disk. I tried to catch the problem via pidstat utility, but didn't seen any error string.

What does exit code 248 mean? And what could be the reason of terminating background process and how to diagnose that?

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Start by adding `return 0;` to the end of main() (this is not needed by c99 (IIRC) , but still good practice, IMHO)

Comment: Perhaps a memory leak? "Enough free memory" might gradually evaporate.

Comment: Why do you `fopen()` a file, `printf()`, and then `fclose()` the file again? You *do* realize `printf()` prints to `stdout`, don't you?

Comment: @EOF: good catch: stale pointer.

Comment: OP seems to be using `stdout` to write to a text file. Why not open `FILE *saved` and use `fprintf`?

Comment: @wildplasser: I dunno, I just don't understand what the contortions are needed for, since `fprintf()` is the sane way to write to some file other than `stdout`.

Comment: @EOF fclose() is kind of a destructor: it close()s the underlying file *and* free()s the FILE structure. So the pointer will get stale after the fclose() call.

Comment: @wildplasser: Ok, but as long as `stdout` itself is never used, that shouldn't be a problem in practice (though it may be undefined behavior technically). But, come to think of it, since `stdout` is global, this may cause race-conditions between the two callbacks?

Comment: `stdout = fopen("log_readers.txt", "a");` reassigns the pointer; the old value will be forgotten. (stdout is not required to be an actual pointer, but should behave like one; mostly something like `&_IOBUF[1]` ) And in that case the assignment would be a structure assignment (`*dst = *src;`) , but the bufferpointers referenced by the structure (dynamically allocated) would be orphaned.

Comment: @wildplasser: Man, I'm too tired to try to grok this today. I'll just go to bed and hope to dream of sane I/O, like `read()` or `write()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't noticed obvious thing. Need to remove `sleep(300)` and make infinite loop like this `while (1) { sleep(1); }`